# RDP to a Virtual Machine. Where should I apply the security measures?

Tags: virtualization, rdp

I have a computer with Hyper-V installed and a virtual machine. I want to connect only and directly to the VM with Remote-Desktop from outside the network.

I have some good ideas to make the connection more secure, but the question is:

- should I apply those measures on the VM, or
- should I apply them only on the host?

I know a VPN or ssh is better, but that's not important. I just want to know if I should do the measures on the host or VM.

Comment: The only important detail, which you leave out, is how the VM's network is configured. Is it exposed to the Internet? Is it on an untrusted network? How are you connecting? "Should" is difficult to answer without some sort of desired goal to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on both. And on the network level too.

I read "from outside the Network" as that you do not have sufficient control over who connects to your VM. So, your VM must have sufficient access control.  Sufficient is, of course, not a precise term, because it depends on the network lay-out, how 'trusted' those who access can be (for example: did they authenticate before getting access to the network?), what "outside the network" precisely means et cetera.

Your VM may be used as a stepping stone towards the rest of your network, especially if you can RDP to it. That means that at least the host needs some measures to prevent such access. Again, this should be sufficient measures, with the same side notes as above.

It must be clear, that, if you allow connections from a network outside your control, you will not get away with installing security measures in one place only.